# Categorize one table based on contents of a column in another table

Tags: sas

I appreciate some help with this task, which I find a bit challenging
I have two tables:
1- Table 1: Containing patients and their diagnosis coded according to ICD code system (the table has several thousand rows in reality)

```
Patient Diagnosis
JOHN    A1
ALEX    A12
ZAK K12
RICHARD A25
SAM G3
MANNY   H2
```

2- Table 2: basically contains a number of ICD diagnosis groups, for the sake of simplicity let us say we have three columns A, B, C each of which has rows representing a number of ICD diagnosis codes, here is a simplification:

```
Group A Group B Group C
A12 A21 C13
A25 A33 J12
H12 G1  A1
K12 K77 L5
G1  J12 A12
D3  A25 G3
```

What I would like to do is create a third table which is essentially Table 1 plus three more columns each for group A, B and C. The code would then go through every row and see if the ICD diagnosis in table 1 fits any of the diagnoses in Groups A, B and C and if so it would fill the corresponding cell with 1 otherwise 0. Here is the final table just to explain:

```
Diagnosis   Group A Group B Patient Group C
A1  0   0   JOHN    1
A12 1   0   ALEX    1
K12 1   0   ZAK 0
A25 1   1   RICHARD 0
G3  0   0   SAM 1
H2  0   0   MANNY   0
```

Could anyone please suggest how this can be done? The tables in reality are of course much much larger

Answer (score 1):

You could use a PROC SQL statement to accomplish this. I did something like this.

```
DATA TABLE1;
    INPUT PATIENT $ DIAGNOSIS $;
CARDS;
JOHN A1 
ALEX A12 
ZAK K12 
RICHARD A25 
SAM G3 
MANNY H2
;
RUN;

DATA TABLE2;
    INPUT GROUPA $ GROUPB $ GROUPC $;
CARDS;
A12 A21 C13
A25 A33 J12 
H12 G1 A1 
K12 K77 L5 
G1 J12 A12 
D3 A25 G3
;
RUN;

PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE RESULTSET AS
    SELECT 
        A.DIAGNOSIS,
        MAX(CASE WHEN B.GROUPA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS GROUPA,
        MAX(CASE WHEN C.GROUPB IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS GROUPB,
        A.PATIENT,
        MAX(CASE WHEN D.GROUPC IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS GROUPC
    FROM TABLE1 A
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B
        ON A.DIAGNOSIS = B.GROUPA
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 C
        ON A.DIAGNOSIS = C.GROUPB
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 D
        ON A.DIAGNOSIS = D.GROUPC
    GROUP BY 
        A.DIAGNOSIS, 
        A.PATIENT;
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

If resort to Data Step, here is one way (given your RAM is large enough to hold whole ICD codes dictionary), maybe more efficient than Proc SQL.

```
data have;
    input (Patient Diagnosis) (:$8.);
    cards;
JOHN    A1
ALEX    A12
ZAK K12
RICHARD A25
SAM G3
MANNY   H2
;

data codes;
    input (GroupA GroupB GroupC) (:$8.);
    cards;
A12 A21 C13
A25 A33 J12
H12 G1  A1
K12 K77 L5
G1  J12 A12
D3  A25 G3
;

data want;
    if _n_=1 then
        do;
            declare hash h();
            h.definekey('group','value');
            h.definedone();

            do until (last);
                set codes end=last;
                array grp _character_;

                do over grp;
                    group=vname(grp);
                    value=grp;
                    rc=h.replace();
                end;
            end;
        end;

    set have;
    grpa=not h.check(key:'GroupA', key:diagnosis);
    grpb=not h.check(key:'GroupB', key:diagnosis);
    grpc=not h.check(key:'GroupC', key:diagnosis);
    drop group: value rc;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Efficiency and speed of array are lower than hash table, but it is seemly not limited by memory.

```
data want;
     set table1;
     if _n_=1 then do;
     do i=1 by 1 until(last);
     set table2 end=last;
     array dig[10000] $ _temporary_;
     array grp groupa--groupc;
     do j=1 to 3;
        n+1;
        dig(n)=grp(j);
     end;
     end;
     end;
     grpA=0;grpB=0;grpC=0;
     do i=1 to n;
     if DIAGNOSIS=dig(i) then do;  
        if mod(i,3)=1 then grpA=1;
        else if mod(i,3)=2  then grpB=1;
        else grpC=1;
     end;
     end;
    drop i j n groupA--GroupC;
run;
```